# NSTimer doesnt work when MPMovieControl playing

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

In my iphone app. i need to check if there is a multisession entry, in every 5 min.
It works great during application except when user starts to play the video/live stream.

Video is pre-payed content so it's the most important control of the application but timer doesnt work on that process.

I think that's because of video is running on a different process but i couldnt find the solution.

help please...

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what "multisession entry" means.

Are you using `MPMoviePlayerController`? Timers should generally fire while this controller is running.

If you go into the background, then your code generally won't run. There are many ways to address this. Start by reading [Executing Code in the Background](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html). You probably want a "long-running background task." That's only good for about 10 minutes, but that may be sufficient depending on how long your videos are.

But start by making sure you're using `MPMoviePlayerController`.

Comment: I found the problem. Something else was wrong that it was hard to see. During the program timer fires in every 3 mins. until user kills the app. If user stays 3 hours, timer will fire during this period. is that a problem?

Comment: It shouldn't be if you're running a MPMoviePlayerController (i.e. embedding the movie player in your app). That way if the user kills the app, the movie stops playing too.